# What does the covariance type mean in Statsmodels.api?

Tags: python, statsmodels

In Python's statsmodels.api package, one of OLS regression's outputs is the following:

**Covariance type: nonrobust**

What would that mean?

Answer (score 3):

By default, OLS results does not use covariance robust to heteroscedasticity (non-constant variance). If this can be a problem in your analysis, you can redo it with robust covariance estimators. See [`OLSResults.get_robustcov_results`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.get_robustcov_results.html).